# Ionic statusbar not hiding

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, statusbar

I have added the plugin `Cordova-plugin-statusbar`. It was working before I updated ionic and Cordova. After Updating, its not working. I'm totally confused and revert back to the old version, then too its not working! Kindly help me guys!

```
 if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.hide();
        ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
    }
```

This is the code I have used to hide!

[image: Status bar not hiding]

Comment: If you want your app to be permanently fullscreen, why don't you use config.xml? 
`<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) is correctly setup and try this:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    return StatusBar.hide();
  }
});
```

Then try adding 'fullscreen' class to your body tag