# ionic 3 iPhone X hide status bar when open camera

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, iphone-x

Basically I'm native iOS developer but I'm developing ionic app with version ionic 3.

In my App issue is that when I open default photo gallery in iPhone X for choose photo then statusBar is hide and looking so bad so how can I show statusBar when open default photo gallery.

Look at below screenshot so you will get more clear.

**My App - ionic 3**

[image]

Actually I want statusBar look like as below that is default in simulator.

[image]

Comment: You can see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251492/ionic-statusbar-not-hiding

Comment: @MdRashedPervez thanks for link but how can I use and also I want t to show status bar when default gallery open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Googling I fixed my issue. Actually for solve this type of issue we need to go on relevant plug-in that has issue and choose your platform and need to fix there.

In my case I had to go on Camera Plug-in with iOS platform.

In the **CDVCamera.m** `prefersStatusBarHidden` method need to just pass **NO** like below

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

and my issue solved.

Hope this answer will be helpful to you.